# How to use constraints in console routes in ZF2..?

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I have route in my `module.config.php` file like this :

```
'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'updatecron' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'cronupdate',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Cron',
                            'action' => 'update'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Now I need to pass a dynamic value to this action like we do we with normal routes using constraints like below :

```
'route' => 'cronupdate[/:id][/]',
'constraints' => array(
     'id' => '[0-9]+',
),
```

but it's not working and throwing errors. While googling I found a way somewhere in [ZF2 github issues](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6316) like this :

```
'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'updatecron' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'cronupdate <id>',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                         ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Cron',
                            'action' => 'update'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

But it's also not working. Please suggest how can I make it happen.

Note:- I need to call it through exec function that's why am using console routing.

Comment: This is the way to write id : `'route' => 'cronupdate[/:id]',`

Comment: You wrote *"While googling I found a way somewhere in ZF2"*... Where did you find this? Adding a reference would be good. I can hardly imagine the official docs suggest this routing. The route id should be defined like @Unex wrote...

Comment: @Wilt I haven't mentioned in my question that i found something in official docs and please check this link where the user confirmed that its working for him in many cases https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6316

Comment: @Unex i am not a newbie in ZF2, the way you mentioned i already tried but through console its not working. Please read question and description clearly before commenting on anything in future.. If you find any working solution please add as an answer i'll definitely accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about route id in my comment. You did it correct for console routes!

I would say that the problem could be in the fact that `constraints` are not supported for console routes. I can at least not find any documentation on this and also [here in the console rout docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.console.routes.html#positional-value-parameters) they don't ever mention adding constraints to console routes...

I also never saw any user cases where constraints are added to console routes. Not sure why though? Maybe it would be interesting to ask on GitHub in the official ZF2 repository and/or make a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints work for `Zend\Console` or `Laminas\Console` since 2.0.

I've just had the same problem and I figured out that the Segment route for HTTP works different. For an ID which can only contain numbers you must write:

- `^\d+$` for HTTP routes
- `#^\d+$#` for console routes

`Laminas\Console\RouteMatcher\DefaultRouteMatcher` doesn't add delimiters to the regex.

**Note:** You should understand that `Laminas\Console` / `Zend\Console` is deprecated and you should use `symfony/console` instead.